# can you reuse the same sd micro card as internal storage thats already been used as portable storage in the same moto 3g phone?

Tags: external-sd, motorola-moto-g, internal-sd

can you reuse the same sd micro card as internal storage thats already been used as portable storage in the same moto 3g phone ?
If so, what steps do I need to take ?

Comment: you can split [adoptable-storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info) with `sm partition disk: mixed 50`